# how to find remainder when $20! + 20^{23}$ is divided by $23$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

how to find remainder when $20! + 20^{23}$  is divided by $23$?

I am finding it bit difficult to solve.  Does any one has a simpler way to solve this problem??

Comment: Use wilson's theorem along with FLT

Comment: WolframAlpha says [it is equal to 8](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=QuotientRemainder[20!+%2B+20^23%2C+23]&dataset=). I think we can trust them.

Comment: @Amr Could you elaborate it?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem , Wilson's Theorem -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem please read these ideas as they are used in the answers.

Comment: @O.L. And when the OP will have to answer a similar question in exam your hint will be extremely helpful ;)

Comment: @N.S.  that was not very serious, I admit :)

Answer (score 11):

Note that $$a^p\equiv a\mod p$$ for any prime $p$, and any $a$.

Moreover, by Wilson's theorem, $$(p-1)! \equiv -1\mod p$$ for any prime $p$.

Take $p=23$.

**SPOILER**

> First, we have $-1 \equiv 22!=22\cdot 21\cdot 20!\equiv -1\cdot21\cdot20! \mod 23$, since $22\equiv -1$. By using Euclid's algorithm, $21\cdot 11-23\cdot 10=1$. Then $ 20!\equiv 11\mod 23$ and since $20^{23}\equiv 20\mod 23$ summing gives $20^{23}+20!\equiv 20+11=31\equiv 8\mod 23 $.

Answer (score 5):

Hints: doing arithmetic modulo $\,23\,$:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;22!=-1\implies 20!=\frac{22!}{21\cdot22}=\frac{-1}{(-2)(-1)}=-\frac12=-12=11\\
\bullet&\;\;\;20^{23}=20=-3\end{align*}$$

Comment: Some poor soul will read that string of equalities and run away in fear someone has broken maths. ;) +1

Comment: @DonAntonio I didn't get ``-1/2 = -12`` part.  Could you elaborate it?

Comment: @Praveenkumar Note that $-12\cdot 2=-24\equiv -1\pmod{23}$.

Comment: Jhehe...I know, @PeterTamaroff : I once tried it with my girlfriend. It was a rough evening, but we got married anyway.